# C# WebView2 NavigationCompleted - Scraping .aspx page that refreshes with static URL but variable content

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping, webview2

As title says, i'm scraping a website to automatize some of my work but i've been having some problems. The page i need to scrape, when loaded gives me a list of items, i filter them filling an inputbox and then sending a javacript "__doPostBack" command. Once the command is given the page starts loading and then gives me back just the one item is was looking for. Now, since the page url doesn't change in the process i tried to use an if statement with a variable to track if when document is loaded i still have to filter the items or i already did and then proceed with the code for each of these situations. Code is something like this:

```
        private void webView21_NavigationCompleted(object sender, CoreWebView2NavigationCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            int Filtered = 0;
            if (Filtered == 0)
            {
                webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("FillTheInputBox");
                webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("__doPostBack");
            
            }
            else if (Filtered == 1)
            {
                webView21.ExecuteScriptAsync("ClickOnTheItem");
            }
    }
```

As you can see, once the page is loaded the "Filtered" varialbe will always be set to 0 so the code won't ever be able to reach the second step. Any ideas?
Thanks and a have a nice day!

Comment: How about setting: `Filtered = 1;` right after the "__doPostBack" call? Oh, and `Filtered` should be a class field, not a local var (so it's remembered between calls).

Comment: what does "Once the command is given the page starts loading" do you mean once the input box has an entry in it then some AJAX happens without a navigation?